# Order by two fields index

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I have an object that has two fields x and y. X represents the price and Y represents the budget. I want to generate a number on witch I can sort a list so that the object that has the biggest price and the biggest budget to be in the start of the list.

```
[
    { "x": 3, "y": 5 },
    { "x": 2, "y": 1 },
    { "x": 5, "y": 4 },
    { "x": 1, "y": 7 },
    { "x": 5, "y": 7 }
]
```

should be:

```
[
    { "x": 5, "y": 7 },
    { "x": 5, "y": 4 },
    { "x": 3, "y": 5 },
    { "x": 2, "y": 1 },
    { "x": 1, "y": 7 }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are asking is, you want to sort by x then y. The usual way to do this is implement your own compare function, without knowing the programming language it might look something like this

```
function compare(A, B):
    if(A.x > B.x or A.x == B.x and A.y > B.y)
         return A
    return B
```